# Ruby, ODBC: MD5 checksum on ruby-odbc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, odbc, macports

I'm following the instructions here, and so far so good, but I'm having trouble figuring out this part:

> Lastly, download your target version
>   from the ruby odbc project page and do
>   a MD5 checksum on it.

What exactly am I supposed to be running MD5 on? The tar file? extconf.rb? I've been poking around for awhile but I just don't know enough to find the answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your instructions came from here: http://www.metaskills.net/2009/9/5/the-ultimate-os-x-snow-leopard-stack-for-rails-development-x86_64-macports-ruby-1-8-1-9-sql-server-more

They give an example md5sum of 36d215...b99 and say it was for the 0.9997 release. Looking at the available releases ruby-odbc-0.9997.tar.gz matches that md5sum. From the command-line:

```
$ md5sum ruby-odbc-0.9997.tar.gz 
36d21519795c3edc8bc63b1ec6682b99  ruby-odbc-0.9997.tar.gz
```

It looks like the tar.gz is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I'm still not getting the same number... Can you share the command you used?

Answer (score 0):

You may get better results if you start from [these instructions](http://odbc-rails.rubyforge.org/), than from a random third-party.

The MD5 checksum they tell you to run has no functional effect -- it's just to check whether the file you downloaded matches the file the producer uploaded, adding a layer of Trojan protection, and potentially preventing headaches if decompression/extraction fails.  You can proceed without the checksum if you trust the source, or if you just can't figure out how to run it.

Let us ([OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of the ODBC Adapter for Ruby on Rails) know if you run into issues from there -- we want to fix things that are broken....